# Printing something once in a while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have this bit of code within a while loop.

$hometeamwin=(lose,win) so with that bit of code above it is printing "winlose"

If there's occurrences of 'lose' within $hometeamwin I'd like it to print "lose" (but only once!)

if there's no occurrences of 'lose' print 'win' (but only once!)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: This looks like you have multiple results rows per game, is that right?  some rows will have a halftime score, others will have a full time score, others have the game result.  Is that right?

Comment: all games will have a halftime section and full time section but because I'm getting my data from a live feed - not all games will have a half time score or full time score

Comment: Also, I see every iteration creates 1 `<tr></tr>` row and I assume you want each row to list either win or lose (which is what your code does)  So I don't get what you mean when you say it is printing more than one time.

Comment: For a bet to win - all teams need to win. For a bet to lose - only one team needs to lose. So at the top of the list of live fixtures I want it say whether the bet has either won or lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem (I'm not positive I do) you want to look at all of the bets and if any of them resulted in a loss, then after you list them all, you want to display win or loss depending on if there was a loss among the results.  I copied your code and added 3 lines marked with #ADDED.  Add those three lines to acheive what I described.

```
if($num_rows) {
    $wonBet = true;  #ADDED
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        if(!$row["ht_score"]) {
            $halftime = "-";
        } else {
            $halftime = $row["ht_score"];
        }
        if(!$row["ft_score"]) {
            $fulltime = "-";
        } else {
            $fulltime = $row["ft_score"];
        }

        echo "<td>" . $row["home_team"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " vs " . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["away_team"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $halftime . "</td>" . "<td>" . $fulltime . "</td>";

        $value = $fulltime;
        $apart = explode('-',$value); 
        if($apart[0] > $apart[1] && $row["home_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win";
        } else if($apart[0] < $apart[1] && $row["away_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
        } else if($apart[0] == $apart[1] && !$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
        } else { 
            $hometeamwin = "lose";    
        }

        if($fulltime!=$row["ft_score"]) {
             $hometeamwin = "";
        }
        if($hometeamwin == "lose"){  #ADDED
            $wonBet = false;         #ADDED
        }                            #ADDED
        echo "<td>" . $hometeamwin . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo ($wonBet) ? "You won bet" : "You lost bet";  #ADDED
}
```

Comment: hmm it's working when the team wins...but when they lose it's removing some other data in the loop. So when a team wins it is removing all the winning teams and showing the losing one

Comment: that's wrong. In fact when I choose more than 1 losing team it only displays one

Comment: what is the while loop iterating over?  Is it iterating over teams or over "games"?  None of my code changes any lists or affects any data.  The break stops the while loop because you already know that at least 1 lose exists.  You can remove the break statement and it will run the same.

Comment: it is iterating over two teams (home and away) half time score, full time score and whether the user won the bet or not. Whether they won or lost each individual game is held within $hometeamwin

Comment: can you post the whole while block?  I also had the $isLose=false line in the wrong place (corrected).

Comment: I'll post the whole while block - It's confusing other wise

Comment: with my code above it is working when a team loses. However if I have three winning teams it echo's win,win,win I just want 'win'

Comment: this seems to be working fine - it was doubling fixtures for some of them but that seems to have gone. Thank you :)

Comment: The only problem is that when it is not full-time - it says the bet has lost

Comment: and when you first go onto it - it doubles the first fixture for some reason?

Comment: I changed it slightly again by moving the check for $hometeamwin until after you check for full time.  That should fix the losing the bet if not full time problem.  To address the other problem you should file another question.

Comment: ahh it should be =="lose" not ="lose" - That fixes the losing bet but not the bet with teams winning and unfinished

Comment: I have to think that it has something to do with your logic then, because if you look $wonBet will only be false if $hometeamwin=="lose" which is true if all of the $apart conditions are false AND $fulltime!=$row["ft_score"].  I assume that if $hometeamwin=="" then the game is not over yet right?